# Can't get work raspberry pi 2 as an wifi access point

Tags: raspberry-pi, dhcp, wireless-access-point

I have a raspberry pi 2 with a raspbian installed. It is connected to router by lan (eth0) and have a static address 192.168.254.106.

Also i have a usb wifi dongle, connected to my raspberry. It works well - i can connect through web interface to any wifi network. Now i want to use my raspberry as a hotspot (access point), and my wifi clients should have ip in a range of 192.168.254.201 - 192.168.254.250 (and wifi AP address should be 192.168.254.200). So, i installed two packages:

- isc-dhcp-server
- hostapd

Here are my settings:

cat **/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf**:

```
subnet 192.168.254.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.254.201 192.168.254.250;
    option broadcast-address 192.168.254.255;
        option routers 192.168.254.106;
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    option domain-name "local";
    option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, 64.6.64.6, 64.6.65.6;
}
```

cat **/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf**:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
#driver=mt7601u
ssid=somename
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
wpa=2
wpa_passphrase=somepassword
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
logger_syslog=-1
```

cat **/etc/dhcpcd.conf**:

```
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.254.106
static routers=192.168.254.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.254.1
static domain_search=

interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.254.200/24
nohook wpa_supplicant
static routers=
static domain_name_servers=
static domain_search=
```

cat **/etc/dnsmasq.conf**:

```
interface=wlan0
dhcp-range=192.168.254.201,192.168.254.250,255.255.255.0,24h
```

When i run *sudo systemctl start isc-dhcp-server* i see:

```
Job for isc-dhcp-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status isc-dhcp-server.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

with these messages in syslog:

```
Dec 19 01:22:58 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[6049]: Launching IPv4 server only.
    Dec 19 01:23:00 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[6049]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
    Dec 19 01:23:00 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[6049]:  failed!
    Dec 19 01:23:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Dec 19 01:23:00 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Dec 19 01:44:26 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[9461]: Launching IPv4 server only.
    Dec 19 01:44:28 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[9461]: Starting ISC DHCPv4 server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
    Dec 19 01:44:28 raspberrypi isc-dhcp-server[9461]:  failed!
    Dec 19 01:44:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Dec 19 01:44:28 raspberrypi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

When i run *sudo systemctl start hostapd* i see:

```
Job for hostapd.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status hostapd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

with these messages in syslog:

```
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: nl80211 driver initialization failed.
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: wlan0: AP-DISABLED
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi hostapd[10258]: hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 19 01:48:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: hostapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And also here is my **ifconfig -a**:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.254.105  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.254.255
        inet6 fd00:adc3:bfbf:0:5b84:2f54:149d:bf8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fd00:adc3:bfbf::f6f  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::e8be:f86a:f528:af4b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00:adc3:bfbf:0:e1c9:c71d:4c6c:d63f  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether b8:27:eb:fc:50:d1  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 34309  bytes 2530306 (2.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 43326  bytes 6908782 (6.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 60317  bytes 17389663 (16.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 60317  bytes 17389663 (16.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether 7a:7b:39:0f:66:42  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And my **lsusb**:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7601U Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So, what is wrong with my config files?

Comment: Hi, your question is well explained. Nice !  You can check driver patch here https://askubuntu.com/a/999709

Comment: Hello, i have already build this mt7601u.ko with this instruction - https://github.com/kuba-moo/mt7601u/issues/64. However, I did not execute the insmod command because I was getting the message "could not insert module ./mt7601u.ko: File exists". I have now executed "sudo rmmod mt7601u", than 
"sudo insmod ./mt7601u.ko", now the Wi-Fi adapter does not work in any form (writes that "no wireless networks were found" in gui)...

Comment: What `iwlist` or `iwconfig` are saying ?

Comment: **iwconfig**:

`eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off`

Comment: **iwlist scan**:

`eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Failed to read scan data : Network is down`

Comment: Finally, wifi was blocked by rfkill. so i added "rfkill unblock wifi" into /etc/rc.local before "exit 0" string, now i will go to next step - enabling internet on my AP (now there is no internet in it)